# Get name of SASApp server (programmatically)

Tags: sas

The name of the SAS Application Server (which is `SASApp` by default) will differ across environments.

In Enterprise Guide this information is available via `&_SASSERVERNAME`.

However, assuming I am in Base SAS (and already connected to the Metadata Server), how do I determine the name of the Application Server?

Comment: I would check `&_SRVNAME.` first; it's a reserved macro variable in the [stored process server](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/stpug/62758/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p184mqqbi9w6qjn1q0619x19eg02.htm) and might be the same here.

Comment: This gives the fully qualified hostname (machine.blah.com)..  Which is also interesting to know how to find, but my case can just use the generic "localhost" instead.

Comment: I assume you've tried `%put _all_;` and don't see anything interesting there?

Comment: Yes :-) It's not there.  Which makes sense as there's no obvious reason it should be there (one may be connecting to multiple application servers).  I think the answer will involve a data step and series of METADATA_GETATTR function calls..  Was just hoping that there might be some kind of shortcut!

Comment: Do you just want the name of the server where your SAS session is running?  `&syshostname`  Or are you looking from something more detailed.

Comment: the name of the _logical_ server context under which the SAS session is running (for which a `syshostname` may have several, as @popcorn points out below)

Answer (score 0):

For the context in which I needed it, I was able to use the METAAUTORESOURCES option:

From the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrmeta/63180/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wdznofxy2l9ln17ldabix1qlmh.htm):

*METAAUTORESOURCES is set automatically for any SAS Workspace Server or SAS Stored Process Server started by the object spawner. The option can be set manually for any other batch, interactive, or server SAS session using a command-line or configuration file option.*

For batch / rsubmit sessions (where the option isn't configured) the answer still eludes..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Allan Bowe for your suggestion to use the METAAUTORESOURCES option.

I was trying to find a way to write in my log which server context was triggered when we launch a Web SAS Service.
We already had in our log the information for &syshostname, but it was not enough because the same syshostname could have different server context.
Now I just need to add these lines in my stored process code and voilà. Great info.

```
%let MyContext = %qsysfunc(getoption(METAAUTORESOURCES));

%put The Server Context is : &MyContext;
```